# How to conditionally render input box with key press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I have been building an URL Shortner. So in the front-end I am trying to build the input box like Cut.ly. For example, at first, I will have an empty input box with a Shorten button. When I post a Long URL and press submit it will conditionally render another input box with the short URL in it with a Copy Button. I've implemented that logic. Now what I want to do is in the Short URL input box whenever I do any keypress it will render the input box with the Shorten button. So, how can I Implement this logic? For reference, I'm posting a demo video.

[image]

Here's my code so far. I am using React Hook Form for Form management.

```
const CreateUrl = ({ match }) => {
  const [shortUrl] = useState('https://cutt.ly/wUBnKby');
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    criteriaMode: 'all',
    mode: 'onChange',
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    reset('', {
      keepValues: false,
    });
    setIsSubmitted(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="create__url">
      <Row>
        <Colxx xxs="12">
          <Breadcrumb heading="menu.createUrl" match={match} />
          <Separator className="mb-5" />
        </Colxx>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Colxx xxs="12" mt="4">
          {!isSubmitted ? (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <Row>
                <Colxx xs="12" lg="8">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input
                      name="url"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Paste long Url and Shorten it"
                      {...register('url', {
                        required: 'Url is Required',
                        pattern: {
                          value:
                            /[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/i,
                          message: 'Please enter a valid Url',
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage
                      errors={errors}
                      name="url"
                      render={({ messages }) =>
                        messages
                          ? Object.entries(messages).map(([type, message]) => (
                              <p className="error__message" key={type}>
                                <AiFillWarning style={{ marginTop: '-5px' }} />
                                <span>{message}</span>
                              </p>
                            ))
                          : null
                      }
                    />
                  </fieldset>
                </Colxx>
                <Colxx xs="12" lg="4">
                  <Button size="lg" type="submit">
                    {' '}
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Colxx>
              </Row>
            </form>
          ) : (
            <form>
              <Row>
                <Colxx xxs="12" lg="8">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input name="url" type="text" defaultValue={shortUrl} />
                  </fieldset>
                </Colxx>
                <Colxx xs="12" lg="4">
                  <Button size="lg" type="submit">
                    Copy
                  </Button>
                </Colxx>
              </Row>
            </form>
          )}
        </Colxx>
      </Row>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: We understand the expected behaviour. Please also add clearly, what is happening right now?

Comment: @TusharShahi I want to implement a logic whenever I do any keypress in the Short URL input box it will render the input box with the Shorten button. Like in the Gif you can see when I shorten a link it shows another input box with the short URL and copy button and then when I do any key press the input box changes and the shorten button appears. I want to implement the keypress lofic here. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the logic. I put an onKeyUp even on the shortUrl input box and then track the keypress event with useState. Here's the code -

```
const CreateUrl = ({ match }) => {
  const [shortUrl, setShortUrl] = useState('');
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isKeyPressed, setIsKeyPressed] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    criteriaMode: 'all',
    mode: 'onChange',
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    setIsKeyPressed(false);
    setShortUrl('https://cutt.ly/wUBnKby');
  };

  return (
    <div className="create__url">
      <Row>
        <Colxx xxs="12">
          <Breadcrumb heading="menu.createUrl" match={match} />
          <Separator className="mb-5" />
        </Colxx>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Colxx xxs="12" mt="4">
          {!isSubmitted || isKeyPressed ? (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <Row>
                <Colxx xs="12" lg="8">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input
                      name="url"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Paste long Url and Shorten it"
                      {...register('url', {
                        required: 'Url is Required',
                        pattern: {
                          value:
                            /[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/i,
                          message: 'Please enter a valid Url',
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage
                      errors={errors}
                      name="url"
                      render={({ messages }) =>
                        messages
                          ? Object.entries(messages).map(([type, message]) => (
                              <p className="error__message" key={type}>
                                <AiFillWarning style={{ marginTop: '-5px' }} />
                                <span>{message}</span>
                              </p>
                            ))
                          : null
                      }
                    />
                  </fieldset>
                </Colxx>
                <Colxx xs="12" lg="4">
                  <Button size="lg" type="submit">
                    {' '}
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Colxx>
              </Row>
            </form>
          ) : (
            <form>
              <Row>
                <Colxx xxs="12" lg="8">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input
                      name="url"
                      type="text"
                      value={shortUrl}
                      onKeyUp={() => setIsKeyPressed(true)}
                    />
                  </fieldset>
                </Colxx>
                <Colxx xs="12" lg="4">
                  <Button size="lg" type="submit">
                    Copy
                  </Button>
                </Colxx>
              </Row>
            </form>
          )}
        </Colxx>
      </Row>
      {/* <Row className="mt-4">
        <Colxx xxs="12">
          {isSubmitted && (
       
          )}
        </Colxx>
      </Row> */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use an empty array to store shortened URLs. When you press shorten URL button make the state true for that input field and use that array to show text in that field. I have implemented the same in my Shortly website. You can visit that for looking demo **[Shortly](https://shortly-vaibhavkhushalani.netlify.app/)**
My GitHub repo has full source code for this website. That will help You a lot--
My [GitRepo](https://github.com/VaibhavKhushalani/shortly)
Hopes I am able to solve your Doubts......